# Convert JSON object string into integer

Tags: android, arrays, json

I want to change the string value of latitude into integer which i want to use in map location determination.
My code is as below:

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
        peoples = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

        for(int i=0;i<peoples.length();i++){
            JSONObject c = peoples.getJSONObject(i);
            String timedate = c.getString(TAG_TIMEDATE);
            String binno = c.getString(TAG_BINNO);
            String data1 = c.getString(TAG_DATA1);
            String data2 = c.getString(TAG_DATA2);
            String data3 = c.getString(TAG_DATA3);
            String averagedata = c.getString(TAG_AVERAGEDATA);
            String latitude = c.getString(TAG_LATITUDE);
            String longitude = c.getString(TAG_LONGITUDE);

            HashMap<String,String> trashcan = new HashMap<String,String>();
            trashcan.put(TAG_TIMEDATE,timedate);
            trashcan.put(TAG_BINNO,binno);
            trashcan.put(TAG_DATA1,data1);
            trashcan.put(TAG_DATA2,data2);
            trashcan.put(TAG_DATA3,data3);
            trashcan.put(TAG_AVERAGEDATA,averagedata);
            trashcan.put(TAG_LATITUDE,latitude);
            trashcan.put(TAG_LONGITUDE,longitude);

            trashcanList.add(trashcan);
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MapsActivity.this, trashcanList, R.layout.list_item,
                new String[]{TAG_TIMEDATE,TAG_BINNO,TAG_DATA1,TAG_DATA2,TAG_DATA3,TAG_AVERAGEDATA,TAG_LATITUDE,TAG_LONGITUDE},
                new int[]{R.id.timedate,R.id.binno, R.id.data1,R.id.data2,R.id.data3,R.id.averagedata, R.id.latitude, R.id.longitude}
        );

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have tried the following solutions but the value of latitude comes out to be zero everytime.

```
int latitude1 = jsonObj.getInt("Latitude");
```

Comment: Did you try just parsing it using `parseFloat`?

Comment: @Carcigenicate  i tried this:  float latitude1 =  Float.parseFloat(c.getString("Latitude"));

Comment: What happened when you tried that?

Comment: Also, what are the contents of `c`? Can you show an example of the JSON you are trying to parse?

Comment: @Code-Apperentice the value still is 0. The contents of c are the string variables timedate,binno,data1 and so on

Answer (score 0):

The value of Lat and Lng should be something like

- "lat" : 22.3361462197085,
- "lng" : 114.1725279197085

You cannot put them in primitive int or Integer. You may want to use another data type like

```
    String myJSON = "{\"lat\":\"22.3361462197085\",\"lng\":\"114.1725279197085\"}";

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);

        BigDecimal lat = jsonObj.getBigDecimal("lat");
        BigDecimal lng = jsonObj.getBigDecimal("lng");

        System.out.println(lat);
        System.out.println(lng);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If you cannot find getBigDecimal() method, try getDouble(String name) or getLong(String name).

Comment: the value is coming null